# What is the difference between red glass diodes and blue glass diodes?

Tags: diodes, packages

I have some old hermetically sealed glass diodes that have a blue color under the glass, which is different from the red ones that I normally see. Does anybody know what the difference between the red colored ones and the blue ones is if there is any? Maybe they just randomly chose the colors, but I feel like there must be some difference...

Comment: Are you sure it's actual glass? Could you provide a photo?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I think he's talking about [that kind](https://www.google.fr/search?q=glass+diode&tbm=isch). I never saw blue ones, though.

Comment: Thanks, I have misread the title as "red glass" and "blue glass" diodes. Regarding the pictures you've found, I alsways assumed this shade of red was the color of raw copper. Never saw blue ones either (don't know any widespread blue conductors), so I still hope to see a photo from the OP.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev To be honest, it took me some time to understand too. I even initially thought he was talking about LEDs.

Comment: I could toss you some blue and dark brown ones into the mix. It is just whatever the manufacturer happened to be manufacturing it with. There is no colour coding or anyhting.

Comment: I have lost the diodes that I am referring to. I am starting to wonder if maybe I was mistaken, and the diodes weren't actually blue underneath the glass... Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the help.